# How do I prevent initramfs from resuming from a zram device?

Tags: initramfs, zram

Whenever initramfs is updated I get a message similar to this:

```
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/zram1
I: (UUID=1d4b8573-7eee-43c9-a02a-10a65fc17b8a)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

However, because all my swap partitions are [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) devices, I would like to disable resume. How can I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can disable resuming from swap devices by adding `RESUME=none` to the initramfs configuration.

Put this into a file named `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/noresume.conf`:

```
# Disable resume (this system has no swap)
RESUME=none
```

Comment: Note that the value `none` is case-sensitive. Some other pages contain messages telling to use `RESUME=NONE`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, you can check if you used the correct casing by running `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: this is not working for me in  18.04. I get the same delay, with error message that it gave up waiting for suspend/resume device.

Comment: @TimRichardson what does `update-initramfs -u` say?