# The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1

Tags: boot, raid, lvm

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu 18.04 server and have already played through one backup/restore loop. So the entire system has been restored from backup with a fresh RAID and LVM volumes.

Now recently, unattended-upgrades has reported this:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-66-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/vg0-swap)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

I tried to find out what that actually means but wasn't successful. What is it resuming there? Some process of generating boot files? I know it can take a while do do that. Does it have to do with the RAID? That is long finished with its resync. I don't get it. And what's actually wrong? What does that message want me to do? I'm clueless. If I don't need it, how can I make it go away?

The server did reboot successfully twice after that message so it can't be important. (If that "I" was supposed to mean something like that.)

Here's some commands if that helps:

```
> lvs
  LV   VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root vg0 -wi-ao---- 400.00g
  swap vg0 -wi-ao----   8.00g

> cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 nvme1n1p2[0] nvme0n1p2[1]
      499449152 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/4 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[1] nvme1n1p1[0]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I can't find a good command to show something about these "dm-0" and "dm-1" devices that are also related to the RAID I guess.

Answer (score 37):

It may happen when you install another OS alongside the first one.
Means that swap partition has changed UUID and you need to adjust that in `fstab`.

To check that run `sudo blkid`, that gives you actual UUIDs of your swaps, `swapon -s` will show which one is active, then compare its UUID to the one in `/etc/fstab`.

If different, edit/create the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` with `RESUME=UUID=<swap UUID from blkid>`. THen run `update-initramfs -u -k all` and if it doesn't complain, you win.

If you have encryption setup on your machine also make sure sure cryptsetup-initramfs is still installed before updating initramfs `sudo apt-get install cryptsetup-initramfs`  If you accidentally messed this up, here's an answer to help: [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: Interesting, but there is no UUID at all in my fstab.

Comment: I changed the swap entry in my fstab from `/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1` to `UUID="5a69d76a-90b4-4908-9eff-10a144b10b4c"` but I still get the same message.

Comment: I ran into this issue after installing a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption and doing the first `apt update` and `apt upgrade` after logging in. During the first cycle, I paid no attention to the initramfs message mentioned in the question. After a reboot, the system couldn’t boot and I didn’t manage to recover the installation. Upon the second cycle, before rebooting, I followed these and only these steps and now everything seems to be in order. Thank you.

Comment: Right Deniis. I tried to install Parrot on a usb. It reformated the Ubu 20 swap and changed the UUID. 
After changing UBU's fstab to the new swap UUID, the swap was active but boot time was quite slower (on a ssd). 
Running initramfs fixed it: sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

Comment: I'm in Ubuntu 20.04 with encrypted disk. My swap appeared in `/etc/fstab` as `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1` and `/proc/swaps` shows `/dev/dm-1`. There command `update-initramfs` was giving me this error. Thing is, `/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1` actually points to `/dev/dm-1` we can check with `$ ls -l /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1`. In any case, I edited the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` as suggested and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I got the message 'update-initranfs' not found.

Comment: Here they ARE identical, and I still get the message:

`$ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda7                               partition       7811068 436228  -2`


`/dev/sda7: UUID="745db9a2-89f1-4c7d-8da9-b57828d2725d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2a0fce6c-07"`


`cat /etc/fstab | grep swap
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=745db9a2-89f1-4c7d-8da9-b57828d2725d none            swap    sw              0       0`


What else could I do, please?

Comment: For completeness, to oneself: here there just was no file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and I am pretty much sure that it wasn't me to remove it.
So I added this file, and the messages went away.

Answer (score 11):

This might actually be a (not even new) bug as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.kernel/xddfBschW0M). They and [others](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061826/835198) suggest to add `RESUME=none` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

I needed to sudo-create the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` first on my U 19.04 machine. With `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` you test and deploy the initramfs image. See details [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-initramfs.8.html).

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` doesn't create `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` for me

Comment: That's not what these tools do. I needed to create the file `resume` (it wasn't there), and `update-initramfs` does its own job (installing/setting up a special RAM-based boot file system but what happens there exceeds my knowledge).

Comment: This and a BIOS update strangely were what I seem to have needed in my latest iteration of "Why in the hell is an Asus X556UB now failing to boot". Thanks for the info on where the file is (the message should really say where to set RESUME and what a value for F-OFF is). 20.04 here. Around middle of the year this started and has been a royal PITA since.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You! I love to learn, especially in Linux, because I love Linux!
My problem was everytime I got a firmware update I would get the resume variable message, for initd.img from 5.4.0-29 all the way to 5.4.0-100, which took over a half hour, probably longer to update my OS, which is 20.04 that I have been running with no other problems for 3 years now, so after reading I tried a series of commands:

First I ran 'sudo blkid'

Second I ran '/etc/fstab'

Found the same swap uuid

Then ran '/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume with RESUME=UUID=<swap'
and set the ID...

Then ran 'update-initramfs -u -k all'

And it started updating all the old firmwares for me . This has been driving me nuts for over a year now. At first I thought my system was borked.
Now I am going to reboot and see if all went well. What kicks me in the ass is that a new OS with LTS is set to be released in a few days. But thats not the point...The point is that I "Learned" something new about linux on what to look for in the future
thanks for all the contributions for ideas to try!
Maybe someone can get use out of this problem that worked for me.

Comment: Hello. It looks like a lot of this answer is just not part of an answer, does not really help to bury the answer under a lot of other stuff. As for a new LTS its more then a few days schedule release is April 21.

Comment: Your answer is too wordy and lengthy.  Please [edit] it to be more to the point of what you're saying.  After reading it a few times, it's still not clear if you found the problem or not.