# volume group vgubuntu not found in kernel 5.8.13

Tags: cryptsetup

I have a new Lenovo ideapad 5 14AR05. I successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with an encrypted harddisk. I then upgraded the kernel to 5.8.13, because I could not use an external monitor with the default kernel. It worked and I'm pretty sure I successfully restarted a couple of times trying to get my trackpad to work. Then I installed unity, and I couldn't boot up in the new kernel anymore, it's stuck on the cryptsetup (before typing password) and gives the following error:

`volume group vgubuntu not found`

Earlier in the boot up I also get:

`initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed`

But I'm not sure if that's related. I can boot up in the default kernel, and because adding unity was the last thing I did, I removed it again, but that probably had nothing to do with it, and it still won't boot up.

I did look at several other questions mentioning this, but I couldn't figure out exactly what applied in my situation.

eta: I confirmed that the uuid in /etc/crypttab is the same as the one in /dev/disk/by-uuid/ and is the one that the cryptsetup is trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to install the newest kernel (5.8.14), and I actually looked up an error I'd ignored for the 5.8.13 kernel. I don't know how I managed to boot into the 5.8.13 kernel to begin with, but when I searched for `The initramfs will attempt to resume from` I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189835/the-initramfs-will-attempt-to-resume-from-dev-dm-1) and applying [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1191018/1133372) worked for 5.8.14 (I'd already removed the 5.8.13 kernel, so I couldn't check if it would have worked in that case as well)